# Assigning a list into constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, python-requests

I'm coding a Hangman game and to this I created the class bellow.

One of the methods is to hide de word with `*`symbols and show the letters that were guessed.

For this, I created a list in method `def hide_word(self)` and call it in `constructor` to show the hided word on the board in the method `print_game_status(self)`.

I'm wondering if the line marked above is valid or is a bad practice.

**PS: Some lines are unfinished.**

```
# Class
class Hangman:

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.hidedWord = self.hide_word() # <-- This is valid or is a bad practice?

    # Method to guess the letter
    def guess(self, letter):
        if letter in self.word:
            correctLetters.append(letter)
            self.hidedWord[1] = 'Y' # <-- This only a test, at first it works
        else:
            wrongLetters.append(letter)

    # Method to check if game is over
    # def hangman_over(self):

    # Method to check if the player won
    # def hangman_won(self):

    # Method to hide the letter on the board
    def hide_word(self):
        return ['*' for x in self.word]

    # Method to check the status game and print the board on the screen
    def print_game_status(self):
     print(board[0])
     print(*self.hidedWord)
     print('Wrong letters: ' + ', '.join(wrongLetters))
     print('Correct letters: ' + ', '.join(correctLetters))

# Function to read a word randomly from the word bank
def rand_word():
    with open('palavras.txt', 'rt') as f:
        bank = f.readlines()
    return bank[random.randint(0, bank.index(max(bank)))].strip()

# Main function
def main():
    # Object
    game = Hangman(rand_word())

    # While the game is not over, print the status, request a letter and read caracter
    while(exit != True):
        # Check the status game
        game.print_game_status()

        # Input from user
        inputUser = input('Type a letter: ')
        game.guess(inputUser)

    # According to the game status, print the message on screen to user
    # if game.hangman_won():
    #  print('\nCongratulations! You won!!!')
    # else:
    # print('\nGame over! You lost.')
    # print('The word was {}'.format(game.word))

    # print('\nIt was good to play with you. But now go study!\n')


# Run program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's fine. Minor nit: It would better to use the term "hidden instead of "hided" — which I don't think is proper English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are only dealing with words, meaning the input is usually short, you don't need an additional attribute for `hidedWord` in the `constructor`, whenever you need this value you could just call `self.hide_word()` .

However, if you are dealing with longer input, like long sentences or even texts, its better if you just called `self.hide_word()` once and had an attribute to hold its value, because calling the function everytime would slow down your game.

Comment: Thx @Issac Newton, the ideia is only store the `*` symbols once in the list. After this, the program will replace the correspondent position of guessed letter in the list with `*` symbols. Like this `tru*c*`, to word truck.